# How to display dynamic dropdownlists in Edit view with selected values in .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdownlistfor

I have a form, which includes three dynamic dropdownlists. They are all one-to-many relationships. The first dropdownlist has loaded values and the other two are empty at the start. When user selects one value from the 1st dropdownlist, the 2nd dropdownlist will load corresponding items; when user selects a value from the 2nd dropdownlist, the 3rd dropdownlist will load relating items.

User can create the form and submit. My CreateController GET and POST methods works well.

Now I need EditController to allow user to edit his form. The problem is how to display the 2nd and the 3rd dynamic dropdownlist with selected values?

In my viewModel:

```
    public Nullable<int> Tech_ID { get; set; }
    public string TechniqueName { get; set; }
    public SelectList Techniques { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> BU_ID { get; set; }
    public string BuName { get; set; }
    public SelectList BusinessUnits { get; set; }
```

In my Edit Controller:

```
ViewBag.Bulist = new SelectList(AllBus, "BU_ID", "BU_Title", form.BU_ID); 

var butechList = GetTechList(Convert.ToInt32(form.BU_ID));
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> butechs = butechList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = m.Tech_ID.ToString(),
    Text = m.Technique.Tech_Title
});
ViewBag.Techlist = new SelectList(butechs, "Tech_ID", "Tech_Title", form.Tech_ID);
```

in View page:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BU_ID, 
    new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Bulist, "Value", "Text", Model.BU_ID), 
    new { id = "ddlBU" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tech_ID, 
    new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.Techlist, "Value", "Text", Model.Tech_ID), 
    new { id = "ddlTechs" })
```

The first dropdownlist is working correctly, but the second is not.

Comment: What problem are you having? And Why are you using `ViewBag` when you have a view model? And why are you creating a second `SelectList` in the view when the `ViewBag` property is already a `SelectList`

Comment: You might also want to look at the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for implementing cascading dropdownlists.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I tried with viewmodel instead of viewbag in the controller and changed the view page like this:

Comment: ` @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Tech_ID, Model.Techniques),
                          new
                          {
                              id = "ddlTechs"
                              
                          })`

Comment: but still got the same error: DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Tech_ID'.  sorry for the mutliple submit messages, i didn't know press the Enter = submit the comment ...

Comment: You have an extra  `)` after `Techniques` which needs to be removed, otherwise it will work fine. Note also you should remove the last parameter in your `SelectList` constructors (e.g. the `form.Tech_ID`). Its pointless because its ignored by the DropDownListFor()` method

Comment: And your error is occuring because you keep generating duplicate (and pointless) `SelectLists` from the original. For example, in `ViewBag.Techlist = new SelectList(butechs, "Tech_ID", "Tech_Title")` the property `butechs` is already a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (and your attempting to get the `Tech_ID` and `Tech_Title` properties of `SelectListItem` which do not exist). Study the code I linked to above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have a view model containing `SelectList` properties, so make use of it rather than using `ViewBag` properties.

Next, delete the unnecessary last parameter (`object selectedValue`) in you `SelectList` constructors - your binding to a property in your model so it is ignored (internally the `DropDwonListFor()` method generated a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `selectedValue` based on the value of the property your binding to)

But the main issue is that your unnecessarily generating 3 `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. The first using

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> butechs = butechList.Select(...
```

which is correct. Then you try and create another one form it using

```
 ViewBag.Techlist = new SelectList(butechs, "Tech_ID", "Tech_Title", form.Tech_ID);
```

but this time it will throw an exception because `butechs` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and `SelectListItem` does not contain properties `Tech_ID` and `Tech_Title` (it would need to be `new SelectList(butechs, "Value", "Text")` to prevent the error, but its pointless so just delete it). And then you try to create a 3rd `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` inside the `DropDownListFor()` method (again its pointless extra ovehead).

Your code in the controller simply needs to be

```
var butechList = GetTechList(form.BU_ID.Value); // its already an int!
model.Techniques = new SelectList(butechList, "Tech_ID", "Tech_Title");
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Tech_ID, Model.Techniques) // not sure why you would need to change the id from the default id="Tech_ID" to id="ddlBU"?
```

I also suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) which shows an example of generating cascading dropdownlists. In particular the code in the `private void ConfigureViewModel(ViewModel model)` method, which will generate the correct `SelectList`'s based on selected values, and can be called from both the `Create()` and `Edit()` methods (both the GET and the POST if you need to return the view)